# Jest Testing - TypeError: d is not a function

Tags: typescript, vue.js, automated-tests, jestjs, chai

I'm trying to add testing to my Electron + Vue.js 2 application written in TypeScript using ts-Jest/ Jest and Chai.

I've gotten previous issues fixed like import not being recognized and others. Currently I'm running into an issue where when I try running my simple test I'm seeing: (look in output for more context)

> TypeError: d is not a function

This however is far less descriptive than previously. I'm also not sure quite what it's pointing to as it seems to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/issues/62) which was fixed when I updated this module.

Of course this isn't an issue when I'm actually running my application and I'm having trouble finding anything related to this even with my increasing amount of sleuthing regarding Jest and the like from my previous posts.

**Output**

```
$ npm run test

> app@1.0.0 test C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app
> jest --debug --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --verbose --colors

{
  "configs": [
    {
      "automock": false,
      "browser": false,
      "cache": true,
      "cacheDirectory": "C:\\Users\\daniel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\jest",
      "clearMocks": false,
      "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "\\\\node_modules\\\\"
      ],
      "detectLeaks": false,
      "detectOpenHandles": true,
      "errorOnDeprecated": false,
      "filter": null,
      "forceCoverageMatch": [],
      "globals": {
        "ts-jest": {
          "tsConfig": "./src/app/tsconfig.json"
        },
        "NODE_ENV": "test"
      },
      "haste": {
        "providesModuleNodeModules": []
      },
      "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules",
        "src"
      ],
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "ts",
        "json",
        "node",
        "html"
      ],
      "moduleNameMapper": {},
      "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [],
      "modulePaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app\\src",
        "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app\\node_modules"
      ],
      "name": "49c9f95751e84975b9ee85f166b8dbdd",
      "prettierPath": "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app\\node_modules\\prettier\\index.js",
      "resetMocks": false,
      "resetModules": false,
      "resolver": null,
      "restoreMocks": false,
      "rootDir": "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app",
      "roots": [
        "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app"
      ],
      "runner": "jest-runner",
      "setupFiles": [],
      "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": null,
      "skipFilter": false,
      "snapshotSerializers": [],
      "testEnvironment": "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app\\node_modules\\jest-environment-node\\build\\index.js",
      "testEnvironmentOptions": {},
      "testLocationInResults": false,
      "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x)",
        "**/__tests__/**/*.ts?(x)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).ts?(x)"
      ],
      "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
        "\\\\build\\\\",
        "\\\\config\\\\",
        "\\\\data\\\\",
        "\\\\dist\\\\",
        "\\\\node_modules\\\\",
        "\\\\test\\\\",
        "\\\\vendor\\\\"
      ],
      "testRegex": "",
      "testRunner": "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app\\node_modules\\jest-jasmine2\\build\\index.js",
      "testURL": "http://localhost",
      "timers": "real",
      "transform": [
        [
          "^.+\\.html$",
          "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app\\config\\htmlLoader.js"
        ],
        [
          "^.+\\.[tj]sx?$",
          "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app\\node_modules\\ts-jest\\dist\\index.js"
        ]
      ],
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules\\\\(?!(bootstrap-vue)\\\\)"
      ],
      "watchPathIgnorePatterns": []
    }
  ],
  "globalConfig": {
    "bail": false,
    "changedFilesWithAncestor": false,
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "collectCoverageFrom": null,
    "coverageDirectory": "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app\\coverage",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "text",
      "lcov",
      "clover"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": null,
    "detectLeaks": false,
    "detectOpenHandles": true,
    "errorOnDeprecated": false,
    "expand": false,
    "filter": null,
    "forceExit": true,
    "globalSetup": null,
    "globalTeardown": null,
    "listTests": false,
    "maxWorkers": 3,
    "noStackTrace": false,
    "nonFlagArgs": [],
    "notify": false,
    "notifyMode": "always",
    "passWithNoTests": false,
    "projects": null,
    "rootDir": "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\app\\app",
    "runTestsByPath": false,
    "skipFilter": false,
    "testFailureExitCode": 1,
    "testPathPattern": "",
    "testResultsProcessor": null,
    "updateSnapshot": "new",
    "useStderr": false,
    "verbose": true,
    "watch": false,
    "watchman": true
  },
  "version": "23.6.0"
}
 FAIL  src/app/tests/app-window.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: d is not a function

      3 | import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'
      4 | import {
    > 5 |   ipcMainToRendererAppChannel,
        |                                         ^
      6 |   IpcMainToRendererAppMessage
      7 | } from '../../../contracts/appAppMessages'
      8 | import {

      at Object.<anonymous>.__decorate (src/app/features/webview/webview.component.ts:5:95)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/features/webview/webview.component.ts:23:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/features/app-application-content/app-application-content.component.ts:24:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/features/app-content/app-content.component.ts:9:1)

  console.log src/shared/Log.ts:4
    not able to resolve rtc url ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
        at Object.getJson (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\shared\ProtocolRequests.ts:28:5)
        at Function.getappConfig (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\shared\Config.protocol.ts:27:35)
        at Object.getConfig (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\renderer\config.ts:7:57)
        at discoverRTCUrl (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\renderer\rtc.ts:7:35)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\renderer\rtc.ts:10:49)
        at Runtime._execModule (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:694:13)
        at Runtime.requireModule (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:376:14)
        at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:463:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\app\features\app-application-content\app-application-content.component.ts:15:1)
        at Runtime._execModule (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:694:13)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.218s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@1.0.0 test: `jest --debug --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --verbose --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-23T15_31_12_028Z-debug.log
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  verbose: true,
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/src', '<rootDir>/node_modules'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'json', 'node', 'html'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.html$': '<rootDir>/config/htmlLoader.js'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(bootstrap-vue)/)'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '/build/',
    '/config/',
    '/data/',
    '/dist/',
    '/node_modules/',
    '/test/',
    '/vendor/'
  ],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: './src/app/tsconfig.json'
    },
    NODE_ENV: 'test'
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./built/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES2017",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "include": [
      "**/*",
      "../types/**/*",
      "../../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/**/*",
      "../../node_modules/electron/**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

**The test**

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import 'jest'
import { appWindowComponent } from './app-window.component'

const appWindowComponent = new appWindowComponent()

describe('Test: Set Title Function', () => {
  it('should set the variable title to the passed variable', () => {
    const title = 'this is a test'
    appWindowComponent.setTitle(title)
    expect(appWindowComponent.title).to.equal(title)
  })
})
```

#### Edit #1

After doing some more, I spaced out imports to see if Jest was giving me incorrect pointer and it was:

```
FAIL  src/app/tests/app-window.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: d is not a function

      3 | import Component from 'vue-class-component'
      4 |
    > 5 | import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'
        |                                                                            ^
      6 |
      7 | import { ipcMainToRendererAppChannel,
      8 |   IpcMainToRendererAppMessage

      at Object.<anonymous>.__decorate (src/app/features/webview/webview.component.ts:5:95)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/features/webview/webview.component.ts:25:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/features/app-application-content/app-application-content.component.ts:24:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/features/app-content/app-content.component.ts:9:1)
```

#### Edit #2

Using [Jest-Fetch-Mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock) I got rid of

```
console.log src/shared/Log.ts:4
    not able to resolve rtc url ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
        at Object.getJson (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\shared\ProtocolRequests.ts:28:5)
        at Function.getappConfig (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\shared\Config.protocol.ts:27:35)
        at Object.getConfig (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\renderer\config.ts:7:57)
        at discoverRTCUrl (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\renderer\rtc.ts:7:35)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\renderer\rtc.ts:10:49)
        at Runtime._execModule (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:694:13)
        at Runtime.requireModule (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:376:14)
        at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:463:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\src\app\features\app-application-content\app-application-content.component.ts:15:1)
        at Runtime._execModule (C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\app\app\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:694:13)
```